# Bootstrap Email signup form with Parse backend

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, parse-platform

[edited] I'm trying to include an email signup box on my website with Parse on the backend.

**Problem:** The email ids entered aren't getting saved into the Parse database.

here's the HTML with corresponding JS. I'm still learning JS so I might have picked up some code from here and there.

```
<form id="signup-form" class="align-center">
    <div class="form-group align-center" style="width: 90%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="get informed when it's online!" style="font-size: 1em; width: 100%; float: left;"/>
        <button id="signup-button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 10px;" >count me in!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signup-button").click(function() {
        Parse.$ = jQuery;
        Parse.initialize("n7cfi9v9FErlM13bSC4qb6obHr0c9lSNmEgyBGTB", "NHA6CciUx6xXCvrQwHGTG48D7ggItvUlrYE36mTT");

        var SignupList = Parse.Object.extend("signup_list");
        var signup = new SignupList();
        signup.save({email: $('#email').val()}).then(function(object) {
            alert($('#email' + " enrolled in list!").val());
        });
    });
});
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Parse? Can you get more specific?

Comment: What is your specific problem? Please add details of the behaviour and what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @fractalwrench The email ids entered aren't getting saved into the Parse database

Comment: @Tarekis The email ids entered aren't getting saved into the Parse database

Comment: What do you mean save in the" parse database"? And what exactly is your code supposed to do? What plug-ins are you using? Are they working? How do you connect to your server? Where did you find your error? Backend-processing, API, data collection? Your question is really incomplete.

Comment: @Tarekis I need to store the email ids entered in the "productionForm" input box on the webpage. I have a class called "signup_list" on the Parse.com database. The webpage is connected to Parse-I've checked it. I just really have a problem with the javascript. I tweaked it a bit from the original sample code, and since I'm still learning js I cant figure out where the problem lies. Hope this clarifies the problem for you.