# Saving input data from JQuery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to get the user to enter their email id into the text-box, so I can store it into my database.

here's the barebones HTML with corresponding JQuery so the code can be examined in its basic functionality. I'm still learning JS so I might have picked up some code from here and there.

**Problem:** The email id isn't being displayed on screen.

```
<form id="signup-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="get informed when it's online!"/>
        <button id="signup-button" class="btn btn-default">count me in!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#signup-form").ready(function() {
    $("#signup-button").click(function() {
        alert($('#email').val());
    });
});
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Help.

Answer (score 1):

use document

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signup-button").click(function() {
        alert($('#email').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: then you have another mistake in your code. see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfwxzfug/

Comment: The `.ready` method can be used on any element, it's treated as `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @1letter here's the larger code that this snippet is a part of. your jsfiddle code works well, but for some reason it doesnt work when I incorporate the logic to the main code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810055/bootstrap-email-signup-form-with-parse-backend

Comment: `'#email' + " enrolled in list!"`  is this really the id of the node?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no `ready` jQuery event on form (see list of available [jQuery form events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/)). Try handling the button's `click` event instead:

```
$("signup-button").on("click", function(e) {
   alert($('#email').val());
});
```

Comment: The `ready` function can be used with any element, it automatically treats it as `$(document).ready()`.